# Is there a way to, not delete a job for specific queue even delete_failed_jobs: true globally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, delayed-job

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def update_avatar
     #some avatar image processing
  end
  handle_asynchronously :update_avatar, queue: :image_processing
end
```

I'm using gem `delayed_job_active_record` with default config for failed jobs as `delete_failed_jobs: true`. I would like to not delete jobs on queue `image_processing`, How can I achieve the case.

Comment: Which is the exact name of the gem you are using? [Cannot find](https://rubygems.org/search?query=delayed_jobs_activerecord) `delayed_jobs_activerecord` on rubygems...

Comment: Is it this one? https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record

Comment: @AndreaSalicetti yeah it's `delayed_job_active_record`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#custom-jobs), to set a per-job default for destroying failed jobs that overrides the `Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs` you can define a destroy_failed_jobs? method on the job

```rb
NewsletterJob = Struct.new(:text, :emails) do
  def perform
    emails.each { |e| NewsletterMailer.deliver_text_to_email(text, e) }
  end

  def destroy_failed_jobs?
    false
  end
end
```

in your case something similar to this:

```rb
class YourJob
  ...
  def destroy_failed_jobs?
    queue_name != 'image_processing'
  end
end
```